# Different url for different language in Yii

Tags: php, url, yii, seo

Is there any simple way to use translations for URLs?
I wanted to change URLs based on the language, like this for example:

- for english:

  `www.example.com/en/contact/office`
- for polish eg.:

  `www.example.com/pl/kontakt/biuro`

Both should redirect to the same controller / action. The code is written all in english so actual controller name is `contact` and action `office`.

How to do that?

Comment: Yii 1 or Yii 2 ? 
There are solutions you need just to search in Google :)

Comment: This is Yii1 - solutions from google focuses on translating application language based on the url but not the url itself

Comment: It would be nice if it could be not sth like big urlmanager configuration but force urlmanager to use Yii::t method for getting true link from localized

Comment: You should at least post your current urlManager rules here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in urlManager (config file):

```
'<lang:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Then in controller's base class:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    if(!empty(Yii::app()->request->getQuery('lang', null))) {
        Yii::app()->setLanguage(Yii::app()->request->getQuery('lang'));
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```